# Image swap with a larger transparent png

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a css image swap and the image I am swapping is larger than the original image and is also transparent (this is intentional).  I need for the swapped image to spill outside the div and slightly cover the  surrounding it when you hover over the image, but it just pushes the other divs to the side and I don't want this to happen.  How do I accomplish this feat using only css?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the `position: absolute` CSS attribute.

Comment: I tried adding the position: absolute; but hat didn't work.